# How to view Http Request Queue for Azure Web App

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

How can I see how many requests are in the queue for an Web App?
 I have performance issues related to that, but I cannot see how many requests are in there.

I have application insight connected to app, but in the metric "Http Requests in Application Queue" I always get 0.

I know there are requests in the queue because if I set AutoScale when `HttpQueueLength > 1` it will scale adding more instances.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HTTP queue length is a vm level metric, so you will have to check this at the App Service Plan level.

[image]

You can also go to Azure Monitor:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I found it in the monitor after a lot of searching, strange there isn't a lot of info on that.