# Can I see Http Queue Length inside Azure Application Insight?

Tags: azure, web-applications, azure-application-insights

My Azure WebApp is having problem with many requests in Http Queue.
To analyse the reason and find out what the problem is, I would like to see the **Http Queue Length** inside Application Insight.

I wonder if it's possible to see the **Http Queue Length** inside Azure Application Insight?

If it is possible then I would like to know how to see this value.

I have tried to find **Http Queue Length** in Azure Application Insight in Portal GUI.

I have also tried to find **Http Queue Length** in analytics.applicationinsights.io.

I have also tried to get **Http Queue Length** from the Azure REST API, but I did not succeed in getting the value.
If I did then I could add it as a custom event into Application Insight.

Thanks,
Henrik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately for Azure Web Apps the answer is no as there is only a subset of performance counters available to the web app process and by extension Application Insights.

You’ve already been looking into this, but be sure you’re trying to get the queue length for the App Sevice Plan and not the Web App Instance via the REST APIs or the PowerShell cmdlet. The link below explains that it is only available for some tiers and only available for the App Service Plan.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-monitor#understanding-quotas-and-metrics

Answer (score 1):

Http Queue Length is not in Application Insights but it can be seen in the metrics on the App Service Plan, since it is a VM level statistic. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45176264/4067411).